# How to import "content-based-recommender" package in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new to React js. I want to implement "Content-Based Recommender" package using npm. After I downloaded it I could not import it. In documentation it said

```js
const ContentBasedRecommender = require('content-based-recommender')
```

but it is for Node js i think. Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know that package, but all imports in React have these syntaxes

```
import ContentBasedRecommender from 'content-based-recommender'
```

or

```
import { ContentBasedRecommender } from 'content-based-recommender'
```

Comment: This is a simple content-based recommender implemented in javascript to illustrate the concept of content-based recommendation. I tried but I got this error. "Could not find a declaration file for module 'content-based-recommender'. "